# How to put HTML element slightly off the edge of viewport to bring it back up when hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, hover, overflow, element

I'd like to code a review section with multiple boxes (one box per one person/review). There are 3 main elements that are visible, and 2 on each side that would be slightly off the page, but move in when hovered over.

Is anything like this possible ? Or should I make a carousel that would slide reviews all around to make it easier for myself?

Comment: This question seems to be off topic for stackoverflow since you seem to be asking a design type question rather than a code implementation question. Maybe you should check out the [graphic design stack exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) instead ?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the CSS hover method to start an animation which brings the HTML element inward.
It might look something like this:

```css
@keyframes slideInRight {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
/* Credit to https://github.com/daneden for CSS animations */

review1:hover {
    animation-name: slideInRight;
}
review2:hover {
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```